# Does stripe allow to charge multiple customers in on api call?

Tags: stripe-payments

I want to create a job that runs once a month and charges customers for different fees.

Is it possible to charge multiple customers in one api call ?

If not, what is the rate limit of the api ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to charge multiple customers in one API call. You'd need to create one charge for each customer. As for the rate limit of the API, it's not published officially and you'd need to contact Stripe's support directly about this [here](https://support.stripe.com/email).